# how to avoid singularity of multiplication of matrix transpose by the matrix itself in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I wrote next code in Mathematica to get the inverse of multiplication of matrix transpose by matrix itself :

```
A = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {3, 51}];
B = A\[Transpose].A;
F = Inverse[B];
F // MatrixForm
```

it always tell me that matrix (B) is singular -despite (A) is random, while multiplication of the matrix by its transpose is ok !!!!!!!!

```
A = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {3, 51}];
O = A.A\[Transpose];
L = Inverse[O];;
L// MatrixForm
```

do any one can explain to me why the first case give me singular matrix while the second case is ok ? and what shall i do to make the first case non singular ? is it something wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brenderson gives the answer here: [B is positive semidefinite (PSD)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593392/119821)

> in order for B to be invertible, it must be that A is a narrow matrix
> (n ≤ m) with full column rank. In the case that A is a strictly wide
> matrix (m < n), there is no possibility for B to be invertible.

For example

```
A = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {3, 4}];
B = Transpose[A].A;
{m, n} = Dimensions[A];
If[n <= m, "A is a narrow matrix", "A is a wide matrix"] <>
 If[Det[B] == 0, " ; B is singular", " ; B is invertible"]
```

> A is a wide matrix ; B is singular

```
A = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {4, 3}];
B = Transpose[A].A;
{m, n} = Dimensions[A];
If[n <= m, "A is a narrow matrix", "A is a wide matrix"] <>
 If[Det[B] == 0, " ; B is singular", " ; B is invertible"]
```

> A is a narrow matrix ; B is invertible